# How to make an setup just like Devexpress installation (v11.1.8)?

Tags: wpf, build, installation, devexpress, setup-project

I want to pack my file in to a single executable file "setup.exe", my application is written in c# and WPF, I know that there are a lot of applications out in the store for creating a installation pack, but the point is which one would help me to build my installation pack just like Devexpress dose ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an UI similar to DevExpress you will need a setup authoring tool which offers an external UI and rich graphics.

[Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/) and [InstallShield](http://www.flexerasoftware.com/products/installshield.htm) have some great UI themes which can get you started. You can also find a list of setup tools here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software

Comment: Thanks, but do you have any idea which one is been used by Devexpress?

Comment: Not sure about the installation engine, but the UI is completely custom. They created it themselves.

Comment: They use Microsoft .NET Framework Installation utility (InstallUtil.exe).

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably have to roll a custom solution for this one. I expect nothing less of the Devexpress team then creating their own installer.

If you're application is not heavily bound into the registry and all kind of windows folders it should not be that hard to create an application that extracts some files into a directory and create some great UI while copying.